In Playwright, how do I use saved browser context from beforeAll() in to the test, would it run fine with multiple workers as well?
In Playwright, I want to login only once and provide the browser context of that session to all the tests. Also I will run the tests with multiple worker, is it possible?
I tried to create browswer context in beforeAll(), then relaunching the browser with saved context. But not sure where am I wrong. I need new perspective to do it.
To save the browser context:
browserContext = await browser.newContext();

await browserContext.storageState({path: 'storageState.json'});

To relaunch the browser with saved context I used this
const context = await browser.newContext({
  storageState: 'storageState.json' // Load the stored state from the file
});


Why do you want to do this? Let Playwright manage the browser context for you. Tests should be idempotent, so you want to share as little state between tests as possible. For login, there's an established way to do that, test dependencies: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth. See the docs page for other standard strategies for handling auth.
